# Bash: Name of directory from which file has been "opened as"

Tags: bash, directory, open-with

How can I put the directory (not full path) of the file which opened the script into a variable? I assume this is the same as $1, so I would like file's path to yield the same result when executed from terminal.

Explained;

```
#!/bin/bash
script.sh '~/foo/bar/file.ext'

#I want to put "bar" into a variable.
```

It should also work when "file.ext" opens with "script.sh" through GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should checkout both the [dirname](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname) and [basename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname) programs, The `dirname` program takes an argument and removes the name of the program from the rest of the path. That is, it will give you the directory name.

The `basename` program does the opposite. Given the name of a path, it will remove all directories and just leave the file name:

```
$ dirname /one/two/three/four/five.txt
/one/two/three/four
$ basename /one/two/three/four/five.txt
five.txt
```

Now, the rest depends upon the shell. In BASH (which is the default shell on Linux and what you've tagged, you can use the $(command) syntax. This takes the output of the command and replaces it on the command line. For example:

```
$ mydirectory=$(dirname /one/two/three/four/five.txt)
$ echo $mydirectory
/one/two/three/four
```

In the above example, the `dirname` command took the name of the directory, replaced everything in the `$()` syntax and allowed me to set the name of my variable `mydirectory`.

You can use them in combination to get what you want:

```
$ my_full_dir=$(dirname "~/foo/bar/file.ext")
$ echo $my_full_dir
~/foo/bar
$ my sub_dir=$(basename $my_full_dir)
$ echo $sub_dir
bar
```

You can also *combine* the `basename` and `dirname` commands together:

```
$ my_sub_dir=$(basename $(dirname "~/foo/bar/file.ext"))
$ echo $my_sub_dir
$ bar
```

When a shell program executes, it puts each and every parameter on the command line into a count variable. For example:

```
$ myprog alpha beta gamma delta
```

Inside of the program `myprog`, the following variables are set:

```
$1 = "alpha"
$2 = "beta"
$3 = "gamma"
$4 = "delta"
```

One more thing with the BASH shell: There's a special *filter* syntax to parse variables.

- `${variable#pattern}` - Left small pattern. Removes the smallest pattern from the left side of the variable
- `${variable##pattern}` - Left large pattern. Removes the largest pattern from the left side of the variable
- `${variable%pattern}` - Right small pattern. Removes the smallest pattern from the right side of the variable
- `${variable%%pattern}` - Right large pattern. Removes the largest possible pattern from the right side of the variable

Here's an example:

```
$ FOO="ONE|TWO|THREE|FOUR"
$ echo ${FOO##*|}
FOUR
$ echo ${FOO#*|}
TWO|THREE|FOUR
```

In the above cases, the pattern was `*|`. This means any combination of letters followed by a `|` In the first one, the smallest match was `ONE|`. In the second one, it was `ONE|TWO|THREE|`. You can also use this to simulate the `basename` and `dirname` commands:

```
$ myfile="~/foo/bar/file.ext"
$ echo ${myfile%/*}     #Like `dirname`
~/foo/bar
$echo ${myfile#*/}      #Like `basename`
file.txt
```

Comment: Bravo @DavidW !: Are you writing a book? ;-). For sake of completeness, I would mention that the filter syntax are also available in ksh (and of course zsh, and proably others).

Comment: Be careful if the script your running is a symlink. Use readlink to know it's true location.

Answer (score 0):

Add some code to your `script.sh`

```
 echo '$1='"$1"

 inputFile=$1

 inputPath=${inputFile%/*}
 finalDir=${inputPath##*/}

 echo '$inputFile='"${inputFile}"
 echo '$inputPath='"${inputPath}"
 echo '$finalDir='"${finalDir}"
```

**output**

```
  ...
  $finalDir=bar
```

Does this give you the results you want?

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your shell is `/bin/bash`:

```
echo $(basename $(dirname $1))
```